# How to Dynamically Toggle Currency Formatting in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports, report, crystal-reports-2010

I need the ability to toggle currency formatting for a decimal field on a Crystal Report.  In cases where the decimal represents a percent, I do not want the currency symbol in front of the decimal.  I currently do not have the ability to change the DataSet behind the report or how it is filled.  So, I'd like to find a solution for this one the Crystal side.

My experience with Crystal Engine is limited so, I'd like to know if this is possible via a report function.  The DataSet behind the report has a Boolean value (IsRatePercent) that can be used in a formula to determine whether or not the currency symbol should be displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution is to use the conditional-formatting function associated with the field's `display string` property:

```
If {table.IsRatePercent} Then
   ToText(CurrentFieldValue,"###,###.## %")
Else
   ToText(CurrentFieldValue,"$###,###.##")
```

Another option:

```
If {table.IsRatePercent} Then
   ToText(CurrentFieldValue, 2, ",", ".") + " %"
Else
   "$" + ToText(CurrentFieldValue, 2, ",", ".")
```